# Getting devise sign_in form into Twitter Bootstrap Modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, devise

Okay, so I want to use the twitter bootstrap modal to display the devise sign-in form.

I am basing my code of the wiki article here:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app

I have the below markup in my application layout file

```
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Sign In</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
          <div class="inputs">
            <%= f.input :email, :required => false, :autofocus => true %>
            <%= f.input :password, :required => false %>
            <%= f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
          </div>
  </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <%= f.button :submit, "Sign in", :class => 'btn btn-primary', :data => { :dismiss => "modal"} %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

And, following the advice in the wiki, added the following to the application helper file

```
def resource_name
  :user
end

def resource
  @resource ||= User.new
end

def devise_mapping
 @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
end
```

It however, does not work. The modal dismisses and nothing happens. The page doesn't go anywhere or do anything. Going to the actual sign-in page works, but submitted the modal does not. Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the code that ended up working

```
<%= simple_form_for(:user, :url => user_session_path) do |f| %>
```

Comment: great answer - probably goes without saying that you must add the gem simple_form   https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Comment: Please could you expand on your answer. Do you mean that single line is what you have in your partial for the sign in link?

Comment: @jagged1 is it necessary to add simple_form??

Comment: can you check this out @DVG http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36037320/how-to-make-a-custom-form-submit-to-the-user-session-path-in-devise 
and please help me if you can.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `:data => { :dismiss => "modal"}`. That should trigger some js function from bootstrap that overrides the form submitting event