# Login modal Window with Bootstrap/Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I am trying to create a modal window for my login (using Devise) on my home page.

I have the following for in my application layout:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3>Sign In</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= simple_form_for(:user, :url => user_session_path) do |f| %>
          <div class="inputs">
            <%= f.input :email, :required => false, :autofocus => true %>
            <%= f.input :password, :required => false %>
            <%= f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <%= f.button :submit, "Sign in", :class => 'btn btn-primary', :data => { :dismiss => "modal"} %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

I placed a few methods in the application helper file:

```
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

When I click on the login link on my homepage it brings up a hideous modal window. When I enter the username/password, and submit, the modal window closes but nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808923/getting-devise-sign-in-form-into-twitter-bootstrap-modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: Make sure the boostrap js is not closing the model on the button click. :data => { :dismiss => "modal"} there is no value in that if your redirecting anyways.

2: Make sure your form has the correct route in the action and has the correct http method.

3: Make sure if the form will submit.

4: At this point your form should be submitting and redirecting to the login page if not then go back and make sure 1-3 are true.

If your mark up makes a hideous modal window then theres not much anyone here can do for you based on the info you provided.