# How to make a custom form submit to the user_session_path in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to make a custom form login using devise. 
This is the code I have

```
<h2>login</h2>

<%= form_for(:user, :url => user_session_path) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Login" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

I generated the user model with the help of devise.
I am getting the following error

```
undefined local variable or method `resource_name' for #<#<Class:0x007f8e54d29468>:0x007f8e49dd7500>
<%= link_to "Log in", new_session_path(resource_name) %><br />
```

This is the source I followed
[Getting devise sign_in form into Twitter Bootstrap Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808923/getting-devise-sign-in-form-into-twitter-bootstrap-modal)

Comment: remove this `<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>` and try.. You need to edit the `devise/shared/links` partial if you want to show those links as the partial have. Because you override the Devise default views, and probably controllers too.

Answer (score 1):

Refer: 
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app

If you have set up the followings in your application_helper.rb -

```
helper_method :resource_name, :resource, :devise_mapping
def resource_name
 :user
end

def resource
 @resource ||= User.new
end

def devise_mapping
 @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
end
```

Then you should be able to do the following -

```
form_for(resource, :as => resource_name)
```